# Google sheets macro not running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with inbuilt macros to archive orders once they have been delivered, however on one of my sheets this macro isn't working.

The macro is fine, it is working on the other sheet. All I've done is copy and paste it and change the sheet names.

The issue is that I don't think the macro is running at all, rather than there being issues with the macro itself. Macros are enabled on the whole workbook.

What should happen is I should tick a box and that order is archived to another sheet. This process works on one of the sheets, where the macro is the same, but not on one of the sheets for some reason.

Edit: I've attached a screenshot of the executions page, so it looks like the macro is running and just not doing what it's supposed to? But it comes up on the executions page whether I click the tick box or not.

[image: Screenshot of executions page as requested]

When I say macros are enabled on the whole sheet, I just mean that macros not being enabled it not the issue. There are other macros in the sheet that are working fine.

Comment: Could you go to Extensions-Apps Script, and then go to "Executions" in the left menu . There you should find a log of executions of your macro, and you'll be able to see if it's running and what kind of error it's returning. Then you can share here and we'll be able to better help you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Tl;Dr Please add a [mcve]. Explanation: On this site, questions that are about Google Sheets "macros" that don't work, should include a brief description of the spreadsheet structure, a relevant data sample, a minimal code sample able to reproduce the problem, the relevant executions logs and the steps required to reproduce the problem. P.S. What do you mean by "Macros are enabled on the whole workbook"? Have you change the "macro" name on each copy?

Answer (score -1):

Open your spreadsheet and go to menu `Extensions -> Apps Script`.

On the left `Bar`, click the `Triggers` option, 
and add any `Trigger` you need.
Then click the `Add Trigger` button bellow, 
and set your JavaScript function to execute on the selected `Trigger` event. 
For now there aren't many 'Events' you can bind to.

You need to double check all `Project Settings`:
[Picture: The left Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgAZN.png)

For the bigger picture just click the logo above `Apps Script`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I haven't created triggers before, I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to be setting up, would you be able to clarify?